# Is there a way to toggle whether or not specific DLC is enabled?

Tags: mass-effect-2

I've got all of the Mass Effect 2 DLC installed and I want to play through the game again before Mass Effect 3 comes out, but I'd like to avoid certain DLC chunks. Is there any way to enable/disable specific packs of DLC for a given character? I'm not seeing any option for this in-game, nor do I even see an in-game list of the DLC that I've got installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way ME2 DLC is handled is rather poor.  If you go into your mass effect 2 install folder, you will find a folder called BioGame.

Inside that, is a DLC folder with a bunch of sub-directories for each DLC.

To 'disable' DLCs, you have to move the particular DLC inside that folder out, or delete it.

This is for the entire game, there is no way to do it per character.